# how to work with Tagged URL [VBA]

Tags: javascript, html, vba, url, webbrowser-control

I am new in this field.

My problem is I get URL when visited gives me nice webpage in web browser but when I try to extract the information using winhttp[vba] or internet explorer method, it fails.

My url is https://search.rpxcorp.com/lit/txedce-165478?utm_campaign=rpxs_daily_lit_alert&utm_medium=email&utm_source=rpxsearch

similarly when I try to download the PDF from the same, the link in the website is https://search.rpxcorp.com/litigation_documents/11809340
but when I use ADODB.Stream to download pdf from URL it fails.

When I visited the PDF url in browser it directs to another link:
https://rpx-docs.s3.amazonaws.com/lits/043/90811/txedce-165478.pdf?Signature=Iw62RBSiCiYAr7gNyJiANyUNjDo%3D&Expires=1452925167&AWSAccessKeyId=AKIAI2UWKALIEYBVOKDA

My problem is, how to work with this type of websites to get html to work with.

**Edit**
I think as it contains JavaScript, It is impossible to solve my problem without use of java script.

Answer (score 0):

Use API to download from URL direct

```
Option Explicit

#If VBA7 And Win64 Then
    Private Declare PtrSafe Function URLDownloadToFile Lib "urlmon" _
    Alias "URLDownloadToFileA" ( _
    ByVal pCaller As LongPtr, _
    ByVal szURL As String, _
    ByVal szFileName As String, _
    ByVal dwReserved As LongPtr, _
    ByVal lpfnCB As LongPtr _
    ) As Long
    Private Declare PtrSafe Function DeleteUrlCacheEntry Lib "Wininet.dll" _
    Alias "DeleteUrlCacheEntryA" ( _
    ByVal lpszUrlName As String _
    ) As Long
#Else
    Private Declare Function URLDownloadToFile Lib "urlmon" _
                             Alias "URLDownloadToFileA" ( _
                             ByVal pCaller As Long, _
                             ByVal szURL As String, _
                             ByVal szFileName As String, _
                             ByVal dwReserved As Long, _
                             ByVal lpfnCB As Long _
                             ) As Long
    Private Declare Function DeleteUrlCacheEntry Lib "Wininet.dll" _
                             Alias "DeleteUrlCacheEntryA" ( _
                             ByVal lpszUrlName As String _
                             ) As Long
#End If

Public Const BINDF_GETNEWESTVERSION As Long = &H10
Public Const folderName As String = "C:\Users\User\Desktop\litigationInfo.pdf" '<=Change as required

Public Sub downloadPDF()
    Dim ret As Long
    ret = URLDownloadToFile(0, "https://insight.rpxcorp.com/litigation_documents/11809340", folderName, BINDF_GETNEWESTVERSION, 0)
End Sub
```